# Is there any special kind of DC motor with no mechanical resistance if unpowered?

Tags: dc, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

Im trying to find a dc motor that does not have any significant mechanical resistance if unpowered. So if i were to spin one up with my finger it would keep spinning. Im not looking for a specific motor just wondering about what kinds of motors there are and which of these would fit best into my question

Comment: Such a thing doesn't happen. The air resistance will eventually stop it spinning.

Comment: Not cheap, but inertial storage with magnetic bearings in a vacuum chamber exist but oversized for you

Comment: Probably inside a spherical cow.

Comment: Do you need it for a specific application, and if so what is it?

Comment: Yes, on the infinite plane of [frictionless vacuums](https://xkcd.com/669/).

Comment: Any universal motor will only have friction losses when unpowered.

not brushless or frictionless though.  eg an  automotive starter motor will continue spinning for a few seconds when the power is turned off.

Comment: If this is solely about the notch torque coming from the magnetic poles of the rotor, you could try one with a bell-rotor. There are small ones intended for model railroading.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Spherical cows only work in vacuum.

Comment: To people trying to close this question as "recommendation for a specific product": that's not it! The OP is asking whether a motor with some *general* peculiar characteristic exist. He does not want a part number! This is on topic, because it is about possible availability of a technology. It's somewhat like someone that doesn't know about FETs and asks whether there are transistors that are controllable by a voltage and not by a current as in BJTs.

Comment: If, as @Janka asked, this is a question about "cogging", then another alternative would be motors that do not use iron pole pieces in the stator:  https://en.nanotec.com/products/2266-slotless-motors/  ...or any kind of motor (synchronous motor, induction motor, universal motor) that does not use permanent magnets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wound field DC motor, either series connected (like a universal motor) or shunt connected, will have the least mechanical resistance. Most permanent magnet motors will have some reluctance torque (notch torque) in addition to the bearing friction, commutator friction and aerodynamic drag (windage) found in all DC motors.